# Using Elvis Operator within String Interpolated Expressions in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, string-interpolation

In my Angular 2 app I am using string interpolation to pull data from a mongoDB. Right now the server/database in in flux, so on occasion that will break my client-side display because, for instance, if I am pulling in data via string interpolation, like this:

```
{{record.addresses[0].zipCode}}
```

... and then, at a later time, the way the data is organized in the database changes, this will break my display - because the client is trying to pull in from fields that are no longer there. So I think I should be able to use something like the elvis operator in a use case like this. That way, if the data is where the client is looking for it, it will print out to the screen. But, if the data is not where it's looking for it, it will just ignore the field altogether - not breaking anything in the display.

So, in short, how would I implement the elvis operator on an expression like I have above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use it like this:

```
{{record?.addresses[0]?.zipCode}}
```

This will check if `record` is defined then if `addresses[0]` is defined under `record` `object` and then if `zipCode` is defined under that object

Comment: You can't check if `addresses[0]` is defined like this because safe navigation operator can't be used on array elements.

Comment: @StefanSvrkota thank you for the warning, I rushed a bit there. I will test it asap. Meanwhile I'll delete the answer.

Comment: Actually, this worked perfectly. Thanks, echonax. In my original implementation I only had the single question mark in the expression. Adding the additional question mark after the first element made it work. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, so you are able to use `addresses[0]?.zipCode`? Then they must have changed that recently, I know that wasn't a case a month or two ago.

Comment: I am using this on an array element and it seems to be working correctly.

Comment: @user2584924 OK, that's my bad then, sorry for confusion. :-)

Comment: Yes, my full expression looks like this:
{{contacts?.record.addresses[0]?.zipCode}}

Comment: @StefanSvrkota I know your concern, I had a similar issue months ago. Thank you again for the warning :-) never hurts to double check.